# Let $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ a differentiable function in $\mathbb R$. $f(x,y) = \frac{g(y)}{1+g^2(x)}$ is differentiable in its domain?

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, continuity, partial-derivative, vector-analysis

If $g: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable in $\mathbb{R}$ I am trying to prove that:

$f(x,y) = \frac{g(y)}{1+g^2(x)}$ is differentiable in its domain.

Here is my reasoning:

$g: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, is defined in $\mathbb{R}$. Then, if $x, y \in \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)$ are $g(y)$ defined. Therefore, $D_{f}= \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^2$.

A function $f:U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in $U$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, is differentiable at $p=(x_{0}, y_{0})\in U$ if partial derivatives of $f$ exist at $p$.

\begin{align}
   A_{1} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_{0}, y_{0})\\
   A_{2} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x_{0}, y_{0})
\end{align}

and $r(h_{1}, h_{2})$ is defined in:

\begin{align}
                 f((x_{0}, y_{0}) + (h_{1}, h_{1})) = f(x_{0}, y_{0}) + A_{1}h_{1} + A_{2}h_{2} + r(h_{1}, h_{2})
             \end{align}

with the following property
\begin{align}
   \lim_{(h_{1}, h_{2}) \rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{r(h_{1}, h_{2})}{\left \lVert (h_{1}, h_{2}) \right \rVert} = 0
\end{align}

Assuming $f(x,y)$, then partial derivatives should exist:
\begin{align}
A_{1} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\left( \frac{g(y)}{1+g^{2}(x)}\right) \nonumber \\
             &= g(y)\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \frac{1}{1+g^2(x)} \right) \nonumber \\
             &= g(y) \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( (1+g^2(x))^{-1} \right)\nonumber \\
             &=g(y)\left[ (-1)(1+g^{2}(x))^{-2}(2g(x)) g_{x}\right] \nonumber\\
             &=\frac{g(y) (-1)(2g(x))(g_{x})}{[1+g^{2}(x)]^{2}}\nonumber \\
             &=\frac{-2 g(y) g(x) g^{'}_{x}}{[1+g^{2}(x)]^{2}}
\end{align}

Similarly:

\begin{align}
A_{2} &= \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\left( \frac{g(y)}{1+g^{2}(x)}\right) \nonumber \\
             &= \frac{1}{1+g^2(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial y} \left( g(y) \right) \nonumber \\
             &= \frac{g^{'}_{y}}{1+g^2(x)}
\end{align}

As $g(x)$ y $g(y)$ are defined, $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, then partial derivatives are combination of $g(x)$, $g(y)$ continuous functions (because $g$ is differentiable). Then, if $g^{'}_{x}$ and $g^{'}_{y}$ are also continuous, then the entire partial derivatives will also be continuous, which will prove that $f(x,y)$ is differentiable. But, I am not sure if it is possible with the info of the problem.

My questions are:

- Is this strategy adequate to solve the problem? If not, how do you solve the problem?

Thanks,

This is my first post, and I am very new to maths, so I will be happy to edit the post to clarify it.

Comment: As you mentioned, this is your first post... Welcome then! For such questions, it is interesting to understand the level of your background knowledge. For example, if you know that the ratio of two differentiable maps, with the denominator not vanishing is differentiable, then you're done without any computation.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Ok, I see. Does it not matter that g is a univariate function and f(x,y) multivariate?

Comment: A univariate function can be written as a multivariate. For example $G(x,y)=g(x)$.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure whether $G$ is differentiable then...

Comment: Nearly everything is fine except you should replace $g_x$ and $g_y$ by $g'(x)$ and $g'(y).$

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you know some theorems about differentiability, for example that if the partial derivatives of $f$ exist and are continuous, then $f$ is differentiable. Unfortunately this does not help you because you do not know whether $A_1, A_2$ are continuous. They are continuous iff $g$ is continuously  differentiable, but that is not required.

In my opinion you need some more theorems to prove that $f$ is differentiable, using the definition itself will probably be not very helpful. I suggest to proceed as follows:

1. Show that the coordinate projections $p_1 : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, p_1(x,y) = x$,  and $p_2 : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R, p_1(x,y) = y$, are differentiable. Here you can easily use the definition.
2. Show that sum, product and quotient of differentiable functions $u, v: \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ are differentiable (for the quotient we need that the function in the denominator has no zeros).
3. Prove the chain rule: If $u : \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and $v : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$  are differentiable, then $v \circ u$ is differentiable.

Perhaps you already know some of these facts.

Then everything is easy: The functions $g \circ p_1$ and $g \circ p_2$ are differentiable, thus $(g \circ p_1)^2$ and $1 + (g \circ p_1)^2$ are differentiable and so is $f = \dfrac{g \circ p_2}{1 + (g \circ p_1)^2}$.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, I don't see why we use gop1 o gop2 instead of $g$ as we know g is already differentiable?

Comment: @IrbinB. $g$ is known to be differentiable as a function of **one variable**. But here we have to consider the two-variable functions $g_1(x,y) = g(x)$ and $g_2(x,y) =g(y)$. We therefore need an argument proving that the $g_i = g \circ p_i$ are differentiable. This follows from 1. and 3.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand it now.